# The 1D wave equation with gravity and the catenary

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, waves, newtonian-gravity, string

I'm in the middle of writing a PDEs assignment and I thought I'd use the wave equation for a horizontal string with gravity.  Easy I thought: $u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx} - g$.  We solved it without gravity.  Then added gravity: I set up the question on what the steady solution looks like, and I got a parabola.

But wait, I know that it's a catenary, not a parabola.  So... confusion ensues.

My mental picture now is that the equation $$u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx} - g$$ is appropriate in the small deflection limit, and the catenary resembles a parabola in that limit.  Am I correct on that, and as the deflection gets bigger, what is the (first) correction that comes in?

Comment: Page 24 of this [notes](https://www.mathtube.org/sites/default/files/lecture-notes/Lamoureux_Michael.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: I think you have to include more of your work here to get some interest going.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** The "leading-order" correction to the ODE is

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\mu}{T_0}g(1+2k^2x^2)^3$$

where $T_0$ is the tension in the middle of the rope, and $k=\frac{4y_{max}}{L^2}$ for an estimated maximum displacement $y_{max}$ and for a rope hanging between supports separated by a length $L$.

The solution to this ODE is:

$$y(x)=y_0+\frac{\mu g}{2T_0}\left(x^2+k^2x^4+\frac{4}{5}k^4x^6+\frac{2}{7}k^6x^8\right)$$

---

That is not the differential equation describing a horizontal string under gravity.

The basic reason is that letting a rope hang slack under the influence of gravity violates one of the basic assumptions in the derivation of the wave equation: that the displacement from a horizontal string is small. If you allow the displacement to be large, you have to account for the fact that the tangential contribution of gravity to the tension of the rope varies with the slope of the curve of the rope. A proper derivation accounting for this fact gives the following set of PDEs:

$$\frac{\partial^2x}{\partial t^2}=\frac{1}{\mu}\left(T(s,t)\frac{\partial^2x}{\partial s^2}+\frac{\partial T}{\partial s}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} \right)$$

$$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2}=\frac{1}{\mu}\left(T(s,t)\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial s^2}+\frac{\partial T}{\partial s}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \right)-g$$

$$\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\right)^2=1$$

where $s$ is some parametrization of the arclength of the curve. For example,

$$s(x)=\int_{x_0}^x \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx$$

This is the general description of the *time-dependent catenary problem*. If we consider the steady-state solution, then $x$, $y$, and $T$ are all independent of time, so this set of PDEs reduces to:

$$\frac{d}{ds}\left(T\frac{dx}{ds}\right)=0$$

$$\frac{d}{ds}\left(T\frac{dy}{ds}\right)=g\mu$$

which is the *time-independent catenary problem*.

---

In the limit of small displacements, we have that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is small and therefore $s(x)\approx x+L/2$ if we assume that our coordinate system has $x=0$ at the center of the rope and the rope hangs between supports separated by a distance $L$. This means that the time-independent catenary problem in this limit reduces to:

$$\frac{dT}{dx}=0$$

$$\frac{dT}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx}+T\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=g\mu$$

Combining these, we get the following single PDE:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\mu}{T}g=\frac{g}{c^2}$$

which is exactly the original steady-state wave equation that would give a parabola.

---

Given this, we can examine what happens when you start to assume larger displacements. Let's assume first that the displacement is in the shape of a small parabola, namely,

$$y(x)=kx^2$$

again assuming that $x=0$ is at the center of the rope. Therefore

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2kx$$

This means that

$$s(x)=\int_{-L/2}^x \sqrt{1+4k^2x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1+4k^2x^2}+\frac{1}{4k}\sinh^{-1}(2kx)-s_0$$

where $s_0=\frac{L}{4}\sqrt{1+k^2L^2}+\frac{1}{4k}\sinh^{-1}(kL)$ is a constant. Let's consider what happens if $k$ is very small, such that we can neglect terms of higher order in $(kx)$:

$$\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1+4k^2x^2}\approx \frac{1}{2}x\left(1+(kx)^2+...\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{4k}\sinh^{-1}(2kx)\approx \frac{1}{2}x\left(1-\frac{(kx)^2}{3}+...\right)$$

This means that, for small $k$:

$$s(x)\approx x\left(1+\frac{2}{3}k^2x^2\right)$$

So now, we can proceed with deriving our new corrected PDE after computing the relevant quantities:

$$\frac{dx}{ds}=\frac{1}{ds/dx}=\frac{1}{1+2k^2x^2}$$

$$\frac{d^2x}{ds^2}=\frac{-d^2s/dx^2}{(ds/dx)^3}=\frac{4k^2x}{(1+2k^2x^2)^3}$$

$$\frac{dy}{ds}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{ds}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{1}{1+2k^2x^2}$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{ds^2}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\left(\frac{dx}{ds}\right)^2+\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{ds^2}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{1}{(1+2k^2x^2)^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{4k^2x}{(1+2k^2x^2)^3}$$

$$\frac{dT}{ds}=\frac{dT}{dx}\frac{dx}{ds}=\frac{dT}{dx}\frac{1}{1+2k^2x^2}$$

And finally, you get one differential equation that gives you $T(x)$ as a solution:

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{ds}\left(T\frac{dx}{ds}\right)&=0\\
\frac{dT}{ds}\frac{dx}{ds}+T\frac{d^2x}{ds^2}&=0\\
\frac{dT}{dx}\frac{1}{(1+2k^2x^2)^2}+T\frac{4k^2x}{(1+2k^2x^2)^3}&=0\\
\frac{dT}{dx}(1+2k^2x^2)+4k^2xT=0
\end{align}

and, once you have $T(x)$, you can plug that in to the equation determining $y(x)$:

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{ds}\left(T\frac{dy}{ds}\right)&=\mu g\\
\frac{dT}{ds}\frac{dy}{ds}+T\frac{d^2y}{ds^2}&=\mu g\\
\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dT}{dx}\frac{1}{(1+2k^2x^2)^2}+T\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{1}{(1+2k^2x^2)^2}+T\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{4k^2x}{(1+2k^2x^2)^3}&=\mu g\\
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}(1+2k^2x^2)+\frac{dy}{dx}\left(4k^2x+\frac{dT/dx}{T}(1+2k^2x^2)\right)&=\frac{\mu}{T}g(1+2k^2x^2)^3
\end{align}

It's actually fairly straightforward to solve the first ODE; the tension as a function of position is given by:

$$T(x)=\frac{T_0}{1+2k^2x^2}$$

for some constant $T_0$ corresponding to the tension at the bottom of the rope (this is analogous to the usual constant $T$ in the wave equation). Given this, we have that:

$$\frac{dT}{dx}=\frac{-4T_0k^2x}{(1+2k^2x^2)^2}$$

and we can plug these in to get our final ODE, just in terms of $y$, $x$, and constants; most notably, the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ terms completely cancel:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\mu}{T_0}g(1+2k^2x^2)^3$$

$$$$

Of course, this ODE is really only helpful if you have a good guess for what the value of $k$ should be before starting. We can get such a guess from the *maximum displacement* $y_{max}$ of the rope:

$$y(x)=kx^2\implies y_{max}=\frac{kL^2}{4}\implies k=\frac{4}{L}\frac{y_{max}}{L}$$

So, if you fix the maximum displacement of the rope at the start of the problem, you can solve for the tension and then eventually the shape of the rope assuming a slightly large displacement than is allowed in the wave equation.

The solution to this ODE is:

$$y(x)=y_0+\frac{\mu g}{2T_0}\left(x^2+k^2x^4+\frac{4}{5}k^4x^6+\frac{2}{7}k^6x^8\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for that.  So it looks to me like, if the tension is high, so that the displacement remains small, then we rescale the y_{tt} equation you wrote by T, and the question is whether  $T_s y_s/T$ is large or small compared to $g/T$.  Is there a plausible case where $g/T$ wins?

Comment: @Joel Yes, the case where $g/T$ wins is the case in which this approximation is no longer valid. In the low-tension regime, you probably need to use the full catenary equations to get the equilibrium shape. There could be something interesting you could do with small time-dependent perturbations about the equilibrium catenary, but this is beyond the scope of both the original question and this answer.

Answer (score 0):

See [Time Independent and Time Dependent Catenary Problem](https://www.lehigh.edu/%7Esub216/local-files/catenary_da3e3.pdf), a short paper that includes diagrams and derivations and behind some of what probably_someone posted.